# iPhone 5/6 returns different CLHeading magneticHeading values

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location

Following code snippet outputs different values for iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 in same exact position. What might be the reason?

Two different iPhone 5 outputs pretty much same values, but iPhone 6 outputs arbitrary values, as if its reference is always changing. I also tried with another iPhone 6+, it has the similar behavior with iPhone 6. Am I missing something about latest iPhones?

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    NSLog(@"heading: %lf" , newHeading.magneticHeading);
}
```

Comment: Are you checking the reported accuracy?  Is the compass calibrated on both?

Comment: @progrmr well I've checked the accuracy, in some devices it is 10 and some devices it is 25, bet after some it changes. As a matter of fact, both accuracy and heading changes time to time, there is no consistency. For some devices when I do the calibration it returns consistent results and for some devices calibration results in even worse. So, I started to believe (and also read from several different sources) that apple has some issues with this.